# Python & Pandas: output multiple results

Tags: python, pandas

For example, in the same cell, I want to output both the table and the histogram:

```
df.sort('speed',ascending=False).head(20)
bins=np.arange(-15, 15 + 1, 1)
df['incre'].hist(bins=bins)
```

But the table won't be outputed. I change it into:

```
print df.sort('speed',ascending=False).head(20)
bins=np.arange(-15, 15 + 1, 1)
df['incre'].hist(bins=bins)
```

It can return the table and the histogram, but the style of the table is lost:
[image]

So, how can I output multiple result without losing their style?

Comment: Have you tried moving `df.sort('speed',ascending=False).head(20)` to be the last statement?

Comment: @EdChum, that certainly works, but what if I want to output 2 tables?

Comment: you may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207990/display-multiple-output-tables-in-ipython-notebook-using-pandas

Comment: Yeah, have a look at  IPython.display.display() function