# More than one Audio object in a Jupyter (IPython) Notebook cell

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to embed more than one `IPython.display.Audio` object in a single Jupyter Notebook cell, but for some reason only the last one gets displayed.

Here a simple example:

```
import IPython
IPython.display.Audio(url="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~urinieto/drop/090412-Incendios.mp3")
IPython.display.Audio(url="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~urinieto/drop/130224-Undertow.mp3")
```

This only displays one (the second one) audio object. Ideally I would like to place this in a `for` loop and display multiple audio objects in a single cell.

Any ideas?

Note: I am running Jupyter 4.0.6, with IPython 4.0.0, on Python 2.7.10.

Comment: You can display multiple "display" objects in the display area of a single cell by using the `IPython.display.display` function repeatedly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207990) for an example.

Comment: Taar, unfortunately this doesn't work when using Audio objects (or at least I couldn't figure it out). Thanks, though.

Comment: I did this:

`import IPython`

`IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(url="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~urinieto/drop/090412-Incendios.mp3"))`

`IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(url="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~urinieto/drop/130224-Undertow.mp3"))`

and it seems to be working (on Windows 7 with python 3.4 + IPython 3.2...)

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly it! Would you care to post this as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `IPython.display.Audio(...)` command only *creates* a "display" object (in that particular case, an object of the subclass `Audio` of the class `DisplayObject`).

Afterwards, you may do basic actions with such an object, tied to the class `DisplayObject` (and specific stuff tied to the class `Audio`). One of those actions consists of *displaying* it, by using the `IPython.display.display` function.

Your particular goal will thus be achieved by the following code:

```
import IPython
IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(url="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~urinieto/drop/090412-Incendios.mp3"))
IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(url="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~urinieto/drop/130224-Undertow.mp3"))
```

The same mechanism is used to display other types (subclasses) of `DisplayObject` objects: `HTML`, `Markdown`, `Math`, `SVG`, `Javascript`, `Video`, `Image`, etc. See [this](http://jeffskinnerbox.me/notebooks/ipython's-rich-display-system.html) for details.

Three things are really confusing when you try to do this for the first time (I was also confused at first):

- the name of the command `IPython.display.Audio`, which seems to imply that something will be displayed; that isn't the case;
- the fact that all those multimedia objects are collectively called "display" objects, while some of them are never really "displayed", just embedded in the DOM tree (e.g., a `Javascript` object);
- the fact that if you create such an object and don't use `IPython.display.display` on it, it will be automatically displayed by the standard IPython interactive mechanism *if it's the last thing created in the cell*; that's the major source of confusion because it lets people think that you don't need to use any particular function to display a "display object".

Comment: Really educational answer. I wish there were more like this.