# How to play Audio in loop in Google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I ma trying to run the Audio in loop in google colab but it is not giving mi any output

```
  from gtts import gTTS
  from IPython.display import Audio

  for voice in ["Aniket","sachin"]: 
     tts = gTTS("Hello {}".format(voice)) 
     tts.save('1.wav')
     sound_file = '1.wav'
     Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True)
```

Output what I want is it should sound hello aniket hello sachin Pleas help

Answer (score 6):

You only need to use "IPython.display.display" method as follows :

```
  from gtts import gTTS
  from IPython.display import Audio
  from IPython.display import display
  for voice in ["Aniket","sachin"]: 
      tts = gTTS("Hello {}".format(voice)) 
      tts.save('1.wav')
      sound_file = '1.wav'
      wn = Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True) ##
      display(wn)##
```

Answer (score 0):

you can monkey patch audio to do it piggybacking on the autoplay:

```
a = Audio(...)
a.autoplay_attr = lambda: 'autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"'
```