# Multiple videos side-by-side with IPython Display

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have been using the useful answer suggested in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048353/more-than-one-audio-object-in-a-jupyter-ipython-notebook-cell) to view multiple videos at once in Jupyter Notebook. Essentially, HTML doesn't seem to be working but IPython does so something like this (given a list of `filepaths` to the desired videos) works magic:

```
from IPython import display

for filepath in filepaths:
    display.display(display.Video(filepath, embed=True))
```

Now I get all the videos displayed in the output. However, these videos are vertically stacked. There is a lot of space to the side and it would be ideal to place them side-by-side first rather than vertically so I can easily see them on the screen together. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `ipywidgets`: Display the videos within a [`ipywidgets.Output`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html) widget,
and then use [`ipywidgets.GridspecLayout`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Layout%20Templates.html) to arange your widgets.
Here is an example:

```
from ipywidgets import Output, GridspecLayout
from IPython import display

grid = GridspecLayout(1, len(filepaths))

for i, filepath in enumerate(filepaths):
    out = Output()
    with out:
        display.display(display.Video(filepath, embed=True))
    grid[0, i] = out

grid
```

Comment: didn't work I'm afraid: the videos still display, but they still display vertically stacked

Comment: hmm, it works well on my side. can you try to update to the latest version of IPython, Jupyter, and ipywidgets? i have 7.19.0, 6.2.0, and 7.6.3 respectively. or it could also be the browser, i am using Firefox.

Comment: Hmm 7.16.1, 6.0.3, 7.5.0 for me. Doesn't sound likely to be the problem? Browser could be, I'm using a Docker container inside Chrome. Also not sure whether my container has HTML or whatever since I didn't explicitly install anything like that

Comment: You can check if any of the other examples here work for you: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Layout%20Templates.html

If not, then your current setup for some reason doesn't work well with ipywidgets.

Comment: Okay thanks! Yup they didn't work which at least tells me what to look into. If I ever get ipywidgets working I'll try your answer and accept it if it works

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add column / row titles?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in Colab for me:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode

html_str=""

for filepath in filepaths:
  mp4 = open(filepath,'rb').read()
  data_url = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()
  html_str += """
  <video width=400 controls>
        <source src="%s" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  """ % data_url
HTML(html_str)
```